# Conversão de site para aplicativo

Tags: php, android, mobile

Qual a melhor maneira de se 'converter' um site (com cakePHP) para um aplicativo android.

Gostaria de converter com todas as funções e que os bancos de dados fossem 'sincronizados'

As funções que ele possuí são basicamentes as de um CRUD normal, só que o CRUD do aplicativo teria que estar relacionado com o mesmo banco de dados do site

Comment: Acho que a melhor forma seria criar uma api no php retornando json e consumir ela em um phonegap algo assim.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se funciona, mas tem uma coisa chamada CORDOVA que gera aplicativos nativos a partir de HTML + CSS, talvez lhe sirva pra algo, tente aí.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer dizer com "converter"? Você pode criar uma aplicação nativa que tenha todas as funcionalidades do site. Pode também criar um site versão mobile e "embrulhar" como app (neste caso, a app é simplesmente um browser). Por favor edite a pergunta explique melhor o que tem em mente. Obrigado.

Comment: Já a segunda pergunta igual que ele faz hoje, precisa se explicar melhor para podermos ajudar

Comment: É, como disse o @Otto é preciso explicar melhor. A gente não está conseguindo entender qual é sua dúvida. E ela precisa ser mais específica, do jeito como está a pergunta a resposta precisaria ser quase um livro.

Comment: Já adicionei informações a pergunta, veja se está compreensível agora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor alternativa mesmo é criar um WebService em PHP como o Otto comentou. 
Depois de possuir um WebService em funcionamento você pode criar um aplicativo dedicado as funções do seu sistema e sincronizar os dados via o WebService. Para criar o aplicativo você pode utiliza várias técnologias como:

- Cordova/PhoneGap/Titanium/Ionic
- Xamarin
- QT
- Aplicativo dedicado em cada linguagem (nativo)

De forma geral Eu recomendo a criação de um aplicativo em cada linguagem.

Se você pode esperar algum tempo o **TIDEKIT** pode ser útil.

TideKit é uma forma de `Wrapper` de várias linguagens para criar aplicativos para Desktop e Mobile em diferentes plataformas. Neste caso você poderia criar sua aplicação em **PHP** e **JavaScript**. E depois compactar com o **TideKit** para gerar uma aplicação para mobile (tanto Android como iOS). A promissa dele é bem próxima do `Cordova` porém promete trabalhar com mais linguagens e com mais plataformas.

Como ainda não está em pleno funcionamento não posso falar mais sobre isso. Porém vale a pena citar.

Segue uma lista de links para referência.

- TideKit: https://www.tidekit.com/
- Cordova: https://cordova.apache.org/
- PhoneGap: http://phonegap.com/
- Ionic: http://ionicframework.com/
- Titanium: http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/
- Xamarin: http://xamarin.com/
- Qt: http://qt-project.org/

Caso opte por desenvolver uma aplicação utilizando Cordova (PhoneGap/Ionic) existe alguns links que você pode tomar por base e utilizar para aprimorar seus conhecimentos.

[Cordova Best Practices](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_next_index.md.html)

Existe também um [ótimo tutorial](http://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/) sobre Cordova com foco nas principais estretégias para desenvolvimento.

Com estes dois links você deve ser capaz de criar uma aplicação completa, porém não existe muito foco em rede, para ter uma noção geral de como o processo de rede funciona em uma aplicação Cordova você pode [verificar este link.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/victorsh/entry/march_11_2014_8_58_pm?lang=pt_br)

Como dica eu recomendo que procure tutoriais sobre JavaScript com a função que você deseja ou implemente a função que você deseja em um site. Depois tente fazer a adpatação para Cordova. Afinal é muito mais rápido debugar um software no seu navegador do que no navegador do celular ou um emulador.

Comment: Fiz alguns testes utilizando o PhoneGap, mas na hora de fazer as 'requisições' para o meu site não obtive êxito. Você tem algum exemplo para que eu possa seguir, ou teria alguma dica de leitura a me recomendar?

Comment: Sim, no seu caso que você teve problemas com as requisições tenho quase certeza que o problema era `CORS`. É o problema mais comum em aplicações com Cordova e requisições. Mas já vou reunir uma lista de links e edito a resposta.